# How to validate keyclock openid access token in .net core web api using openidconnect library

Tags: validation, keycloak, access-token, webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to validate openid access token in middleware web api with openidconnect library in .netcore6.0,below steps i have used

1. Created console application and get the access token from keycloak by creating browser through openid connect login
2. send that access token to middleware web api by adding bearer in authorization headers
3. validate that access token in middleware web api using using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` library

how to do it? i tried many ways but did not get solution

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
options.Authority = authority;
options.ClientId = clientId;
options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
options.SaveTokens = true;
//todo dont use in prod?
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```